# jQuery help retrieving Data from JSON object using Fan Feedr API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am using Fan Feedr API and I am having trouble displaying JSON as view-able data. I am able to get the content succesfully however I seem to be having issues displaying the data in my console or as HTML on success...

**Here is my jQuery...**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://ffapi.fanfeedr.com/basic/api/teams/3575a829-cae3-574e-a56a-60b6b1b5a7b7/content?api_key=097879879',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**My HTML...**

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

**And a fiddle I started...**

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/vKTaZ/1/

I feel like this should work, so I am thinking I am missing something basic. But I can't seem to spot it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Fan Feedr link... http://developer.fanfeedr.com/

Comment: Okay.. When I use JSON.. I get this error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ffapi.fanfeedr.com/basic/api/teams/3575a829-cae3-574e-a56a-60b6b1b5a7b7/content?api_key=......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FanFeedr API does not (currently) support JSONP](http://developer.fanfeedr.com/Overview), so you cannot make a cross-domain request in this manner.

Comment: So should I use dataType:"json" then?

Comment: No; you need to make the API request on your server and not in the browser, because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Okay so instead of using AJAX I need to use a server side script like PHP?